# How to create a bitmap from assembly, using allegro?

Tags: c, assembly, bitmap, allegro

My task is to generate fractal in C. The problem is that all computing must be done in x86 assembly, in a function defined by me.

I chose allegro5 library to do it. My question is:
Is there any possibility to get an address of allocated memory for bitmap by function?

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *al_create_bitmap(int w, int h)
```

Of course I mean bitmap, not ALLEGRO_BITMAP structure.
And will ALLEGRO_BITMAP structure work properly after coloring?
I read something that it shouldn't be modified by any other functions except this from documentation :)

Comment: Without knowing anything about Allegro, have you considered making calls from your assembly-language implementation of the fractal calculation into the library's API for painting in a bitmap?  The same way the compiler would do it, if you wrote the calculation in C and used the documented API?

Comment: Been almost 2 decades since I last used Allegro, but perhaps something like [al_lock_bitmap](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_lock_bitmap)...

Comment: I think i get your idea. For example,  in assembly , store all colors in array. Return it to C and then use the function in a loop colorPixel(posx , posy ,array[i])  from API? The key thing is that I should edit bitmap directly in assembly.

Comment: @AleksanderNuszel did you check my link...

Comment: If you call a C function from your assembly, your code is going to be most probably slower than a corresponding C code that would be generated by an optimizing compiler.

Comment: I answered to @zwol . Thanks for your help. I think that this will solve my problem!

Comment: @AleksanderNuszel If you should edit the bitmap directly from assembly, then the function at Antti Haapala's link does look like what you want, rather than my suggestion.

Comment: Can you return by *value*, so the caller allocates space for the bitmap?  Anyway, yeah you should probably see how the bitmap type is defined and deal with it yourself in asm, because there's no compiler to inline simple wrapper functions for you.  You want to be doing stuff like `vmovmskps eax, ymm0` / `mov [rdi], al` to store 8 bits of bitmap at once, from 8 packed floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`al_lock_bitmap` gives you an `ALLEGRO_LOCKED_REGION` which tells you the data address, the pitch, and stride of the locked region. You can edit the memory directly. Then when you are done, call `al_unlock_bitmap` to upload the changes.